# FooterView receiving the ListView click event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with a footer view. I have se t a listener for the `ListView`. The problem is that when I'm pressing a text view of the footer view, the `onItemClick` method is called, and I receive a `NullPointerException`, because the footer view doesn't have the list row layout. Is that normal? Or is there a workaround for this?

This is the footer layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    style="@style/GreyTitleTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/about_us_title"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:background="@drawable/white_round_rect" >   
    <TextView 
        style="@style/GreyTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="@string/contact_title" />
    <ImageView  
        style="@style/OrangeArrowImageView"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_half_medium"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/credits"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:background="@drawable/white_round_rect" >   
    <TextView
        style="@style/GreyTextView"  
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="@string/credits_title" />
    <ImageView  
        style="@style/OrangeArrowImageView"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_half_medium"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where the text view style is:

```
<style name="GreyTitleTextView" parent="GreyTextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/news_date_tv_bg</item>
</style>
```

The log is not important. It's a simple NPE, because I'm handling the pressed view as if it's a listview row.

Comment: plz add your code and log trace